# Do you really need a pipe out for potential harmful gas for pump

Tags: sump-pump, sewer, filter, air-quality

I recently replaced a Laundry pump, the laundry pump has 2 connections out, one is a pvc pipe out to the drain, the other opening is for piping out gas/air from sewer system. Currently, I have the other opening just there, without attaching a pipe to go to outside of the house.

Home Depot is selling this air filter thing, that I can connect to that opening, supposed to filter out the gas / air. My question is, is it worth it? I don't seem to smell or experience any leak gas/air from the sewer.

Should I install the air filter? or should I install the pipe out to the house.
Is there potential harmful effects from the sewer gas? how do I even test to see if there is any potential gas/air from sewer?

Here's [the pump](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-0-25-HP-Pre-Plumbed-Sink-Tray-System-Sump-Pump-THD1035/205616019?keyword=everbilt%20laundry%20pump) that I installed. Here's [the manual](https://www.manualshelf.com/manual/everbilt/thd1035/1-instructions-assembly.html). Here's the [air admittance valve](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sure-Vent-1-1-2-in-x-2-in-PVC-Air-Admittance-Valve-39016/100201861).

Diagram from the manual:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do you really need a pipe out for potential harmful gas for pump?*

Not in an otherwise properly plumbed system, but you should consider adding a stand pipe to help protect yourself from an overflow during a system failure.

---

As long as there's a check valve on the discharge pipe that would mean there's no chance for sewer gas, just moldy bucket smell after a while, possibly. With a sink also tapped into it you might want to pipe it to your stack, but with just a washing machine and all the soap going through it, it should be fine.

**They're talking about an *air admittance valve*, which you don't need necessarily but you could add one if the bucket starts to smell.** Here's a picture showing a piece of pipe open to the air, doing absolutely nothing as far as odor mitigation, which is fine because the system has a check valve and probably doesn't see much kitchen waste or the like.

That additional length of vent pipe would however allow you to fill the sink without flooding the floor in the event of a pump failure, before you realized it had. It also additionally increases the holding capacity of the pump to the size of the sink. So if you have a similar setup and you do install an AAV, you might as well put a length of pipe on it too. Also, should the check valve ever fail, having it elbowed into the sink would help prevent more catastrophes, and unless it at least has a stand pipe you won't get that extra holding capacity.

[image]

([source](https://www.plbg.com/forum/read.php?1,571229))

Comment: No, there are 3 holes, I read the manual. :) 1 is the inlet, 1 is the outlet, and 1 is for getting rid of the methane gas. Inlet is connected, outlet connected to the drain, and the hole for gas is left open there without anything. It's been running for a few weeks now after I installed it. So far I haven't notice any smells or anything near the basement. Today, my wife called and said she smelled something upstairs. (The pump is at the basement.)

Comment: That's exactly the same pump that I have. So the one labeled "vent" is absolutely useless in your picture?

Comment: @rvpals - No, without that hole or with it plugged, it would suck the sink's trap dry. That piece of pipe is useless, but the pump's air inlet ("vent") is not. It's not really a sewer vent, it's more of an air inlet that you can pipe to your stack if you want, because if you tap a sink into it, it prob will get smelly.

Comment: You're right. I was talking about air admittance valve. like this: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sure-Vent-1-1-2-in-x-2-in-PVC-Air-Admittance-Valve-39016/100201861

Do you think I need to stick one in that hole called "vent".

Comment: your picture shows almost exactly the same setup that I have. Sink goes to the horizontal opening, pvs pipe out to sewer is connected, the one with vent is currently left with nothing (just a hole), should I do what you did in that picture, just attach a piece of long pvc pipe? I don't see the purpose of you pipe the vent over to the laundry sink, don't think water is ever going to overflow out from that opening?

Comment: @rvpals - It will never overflow out that pipe because that elbow is above the lip of the sink. Read the last paragraph to see why (in the event of pump or check valve failure you just have a sink that doesn't drain, not a flood).